# Using MikePenz drawer, where can i handle onDrawerOpen, close soft keyboard

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, android-softkeyboard, materialdrawer

i am using mikepenz drawer, i want my softkeyboard to be closed when ik open my drawer, didnt have a problem with doing this with the on hamburger item press, but can find where to handle closing the keyboard on opening the drawer by sliding.

Comment: Did you implement the `OnDrawerListener` [here](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/Drawer.java#L1056) as part of the `DrawerBuilder` class with method `withOnDrawerListener`?

Comment: @t0mm13b, .... how can i have read over this. thanks a lot dude

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after the information t0mm13b pointed me to, this is how i did it.

```
    result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withTranslucentStatusBar(false)
            .withActionBarDrawerToggle(false)
            .addDrawerItems(drawerItemsArray)
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .withOnDrawerListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerSlide(View view, float v) {
                    removeSoftKeyboard();
                }
            })
            .build();
```

remove soft keyboard method

```
public void removeSoftKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```